# Sitecore patch from Security Bulletin SC2017-001-170504

Tags: richtext-editor, update-packages

I am trying to install the https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/978654 to a SC 8.2 update 2 instance. Once installed I am getting the following error when I open the rich text editor. It looks like it is looking for the Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd handler but this patch requires it to be removed. Any ideas?

```
ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: '~/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd' is missing in web.config. RadScriptManager requires a HttpHandler registration in web.config. Please, use the control Smart Tag to add the handler automatically, or see the help for more information: Controls > RadScriptManager
Source: Telerik.Web.UI
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadScriptManager.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, read carefully security bulletin. There is written:

> Sitecore strongly recommends that all customers remove the following
>   configuration from any Sitecore servers except Content Management,
>   which requires these controls.

These handlers are still required on CM servers. And there is nothing wrong with security bulletin.

Comment: Completely missed that line. How do I uninstall stack exchange?

Answer (score 2):

Removing `Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd` and other Telerik handlers should be done on any Sitecore servers **except Content Management**, which requires these controls. On **Content Management** server those handlers should stay as they are plus additionally:

On CM server you should:

1. Extract the contents of the patch from your to the Sitecore website folder.
2. Add the following lines to `<appSettings>` node:

```xml
<add key="Telerik.AsyncUpload.ConfigurationEncryptionKey" value="YOUR_ENCRYPTION_KEY_HERE"  />
<add key="Telerik.Upload.ConfigurationHashKey" value="YOUR_ENCRYPTION_KEY_HERE" />
<add key="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogParametersEncryptionKey" value="YOUR_ENCRYPTION_KEY_HERE" />
```

3. Replace `YOUR_ENCRYPTION_KEY_HERE` with minimum 32 random characters.
4. And add:

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Web.UI" publicKeyToken="121fae78165ba3d4" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2015.1.401.45" newVersion="2017.2.621.45" />  
</dependentAssembly>
```

The same steps should be done on **Standalone** servers.